# displaying message users in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, message

I want to get the list of users messages sent

I am using `users_id` to store the receivers id and `sender_id` to store the senders id I want to display the message users listing as in whatsapp or in fb messenger

I have tried using

```
$message    =  Messages::whereRaw("(sender_id, `users_id`, `created_at`) IN (
              SELECT   sender_id, `users_id`, MAX(`created_at`)
              FROM     messages
              WHERE     `users_id`=$userId
                or    `sender_id`=$userId
              GROUP BY sender_id, `users_id`)")
              ->skip($start)->take(51)
              ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
              ->get();
```

This fetches the data of last two conversation between those users

Is there a way to get the last data stored whether sent or received by an user??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several try, I ended up in creating a field for `conversationId` and grouped the messages under that id so that **there is only one unique `conversationId`** between two users

```
$message    =  Messages::whereRaw("(sender_id, `users_id`, `created_at`) IN (
          SELECT   sender_id, `users_id`, MAX(`created_at`)
          FROM     messages
          WHERE     `users_id`=$userId
            or    `sender_id`=$userId
          GROUP BY conversationId)")
          ->skip($start)->take(50)
          ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
          ->get();
```

The conversation id is created if there is no existing conversation between the two users